# Pandoc: autogenerate and autoreload reveal.js slides on markdown modification

Tags: pandoc, reveal.js

I am using `pandoc` to generate some slides for `reveal.js`. Now, when I edit the markdown file, I have to manually regenerate the HTML and then manually reload it in my browser to see the changes.

Is there a way to automate this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Update

I ended up creating a Python package for this: [Markdownreveal](https://github.com/markdownreveal/markdownreveal).

You can install it with:

```
pip install markdownreveal
```

And start working with your presentations with:

```
markdownreveal my_presentation.md
```

You can customize the style, generate ZIPs or PDFs, upload to GitHub pages... For more information, have a look at the [full project's documentation](https://markdownreveal.readthedocs.io/).

### Old answer

Well, there is no way to configure `pandoc` to do that. But you can always create a script.

[I made a script called `pandoc-watch`](https://github.com/Peque/peque/blob/master/bin/pandoc-watch) that watches the markdown file and, on modification (when you save your changes), it will automatically regenerate the HTML for `reveal.js` and it will be reloaded in your browser, using `reveal.js`'s local server.

Note:

- Made for GNU/Linux OSs.
- Requires: `bash`, `curl`, `npm`, `grunt`, `inotifywait`.
- Usage: `pandoc-watch markdown_slides.md`.
- It is only meant for `reveal.js` output!
- The first time is run it will download `reveal.js` and all the required `node.js` packages, so it may take some time. All the downloaded files are kept in `~/.pandoc-watch`, in case you want to clean everything.

Comment: interesting approach, however the links to the script are broken. A pandoc-watch can now be found at https://github.com/dloureiro/pandoc-watch